# rangeOfString and NSMakeRange : from Objective-C to Java

Tags: java, android, objective-c, translate, code-translation

I have this following Objective-C code and I want to translate it into Java code (for Android).

I know I have to use `indexOf()` but I don't know how to adapt `range:NSMakeRange( old_position, ([currentWord length] - old_position)` into Java

```
    NSRange end = [currentWord rangeOfString:@"]"  options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange( old_position, ([currentWord length] - old_position))];

    if ( end.location != NSNotFound ) {                     
        old_position = end.location + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the whole Objective-C method? This way we can know what `old_position` is and what you are trying to do on a higher level of abstraction.

Comment: @Sweeper unfortunately the function is very long and "dirty", but here is the whole code : gist.github.com/kevin-valerio/4f60a334adaeea37ac4daa338c858b83. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rangeOfString:options:range:` method is quite similar to the `indexOf(str, fromIndex)` method.

Try this:

```
Integer start = currentWord.indexOf("[", old_position);
```

Since the parameter is called `fromPosition`, you should pass the position from which you want to search, instead of the length of the portion that you want to search.